# Flickr 4 Java - How do you find pictures / metadata from a certain region? e.g. Vienna

Tags: java, api, flickr

Best

**Goal :** 
Receiving geographic data(coordinates), time-stamps... . "From pictures taken in Vienna."

**My question:** 
How can i do this in Java? (using flickrapi-1.2.jar)

**What did i already found out? :**
Give me the 500 most recent pictures - url's ... :s

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FlickrException, IOException,
        SAXException {

    String apiKey = "123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwuxz";

    Flickr f = new Flickr(apiKey);

    PhotosInterface photosInterface = f.getPhotosInterface();
    Collection photosCollection = null;
    photosCollection = photosInterface.getRecent(500, 0);

    int i = 0;

    Photo photo = null;
    Iterator photoIterator = photosCollection.iterator();
    while (photoIterator.hasNext()) {
        i++;
        photo = (Photo) photoIterator.next();
        System.out.println(i + " - Description: " + photo.getSmallUrl());

    }
}
```

**Option :** Good Examples or a decent manual is welkom, because i don't know exactly how this API works...

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the [flickr.photos.search](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html) API method.

With Flickr4Java it would look like this:

```
    String apikey;
    String secret;

    // Create a Flickr instance with your data. No need to authenticate
    Flickr flickr = new Flickr(apikey, secret, new REST());

    // Set the wanted search parameters (I'm not using real variables in the example)
    SearchParameters searchParameters = new SearchParameters();
    searchParameters.setAccuracy(accuracyLevel);
    searchParameters.setBBox(minimum_longitude, 
                                 minimum_latitude, 
                                 maximum_longitude, 
                                 maximum_latitude);

    PhotoList<Photo> list = flickr.getPhotosInterface().search(searchParameters, 0, 0);

    // Do something with the list
```